# Log-likelihood in regime switching

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Not sure if this question is too simple to be asked here...

In the following paper

- Cho, Jin Seo, and Halbert White. ["Testing for regime switching."](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.343&rep=rep1&type=pdf) *Econometrica* **75**.6 (2007): 1671-1720. doi: [10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00809.x)

on page 1675, there is the following formula:
$$ \log(P(X_1,\dots,X_n))= \log\left(\boldsymbol{\pi}'\cdot \prod^n_{i=1} P F_i(\theta)\cdot \mathbf{1}\right)$$

The $\lbrace X_i\rbrace$ is a hidden Markov chain, where the $\lbrace S_i\rbrace$ is the Markov chain associated with it.

How do I prove it?

$$\displaystyle P(X_2|X_1)=E(P(X_2|X_1,S_1,S_2))=E(E(P(X_2|X_1,S_1,S_2)|S_1))$$
$$=E(F(X_2|X_1,S_1,\theta_1)\cdot p_{i1}+F(X_2|X_1,S_1,\theta_2)\cdot p_{i2})$$
$$\displaystyle =\sum^2_{i=1}\left(F(X_2|X_1,S_1,\theta_1)\cdot p_{i1}+F(X_2|X_1,S_1,\theta_2)\cdot p_{i2} \right)\cdot P(S_1=i)=\boldsymbol{\pi}'\cdot \boldsymbol{PF}_2(\theta)\cdot \mathbf{1}$$

where $(P(S_1=1)P(S_1=2))= \boldsymbol{\pi}'$, $\boldsymbol{P}$ is the 2x2 transition matrix as in the paper. \

Using a analogous reasoning we get:
$$P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1)=E(E(P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1,S_{n-1},S_n)|S_{n-1}))$$
$$=(P(S_{n-1}=1)P(S_{n-1}=2))'\cdot \boldsymbol{PF}_n(\theta)\cdot \mathbf{1}=\boldsymbol{\pi}'\cdot \boldsymbol{P}^{n-1} \boldsymbol{F}_n(\theta)\cdot \mathbf{1}$$

Also, we have:
$$P(X_2,\dots,X_n|X_1)=P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1)\cdot P(X_{n-1}|X_{n-2},\dots,X_1)\cdot \dots \cdot P(X_2|X_1) $$

$$\displaystyle Log(P(X_2,\dots,X_n|X_1)= Log( \prod^{n}_{i=1}\boldsymbol{\pi}'\cdot \boldsymbol{P}^{i-1} \boldsymbol{F}_i(\theta)\cdot \mathbf{1})$$

Which is,however, different from what is on the paper:

$$\displaystyle Log(P(X_2,\dots,X_n|X_1)= Log(\boldsymbol{\pi}'\cdot \prod^n_{i=1} \boldsymbol{P F}_i\cdot \mathbf{1})$$

So, where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that you're computing expectations without conditioning on the available evidence. More formally, some of the equations with implicit sums are incomplete. For example, here:
$$P(X_2|X_1)=E(P(X_2|X_1,S_1,S_2))?$$
That isn't quite right if taken literally:
$$P(X_2|X_1)=\sum_{s_1,s_2}P(X_2|X_1,S_1,S_2)P(S_1,S_2)?$$
It should be:
$$P(X_2|X_1)=\sum_{s_1,s_2}P(X_2|X_1,S_1,S_2)P(S_1,S_2|X_1).$$

Later, in the computations for general $n$, the unconditional probabilities $\boldsymbol{\pi}'=(P(S_{n-1}=1)P(S_{n-1}=2))$ shouldn't appear so early. Instead, we should see terms like $P(S_{n-1}=1|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1)$. (But I haven't worked out the full expression involving the latter.)

---

Edit: After discussion in the comments, I understand what you're attempting a little more clearly. The above issue was a bit of a red herring. There is an improper marginalization in the equation that defines your overall strategy:
$$P(X_2,\dots,X_n|X_1)=P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1)\cdot P(X_{n-1}|X_{n-2},\dots,X_1)\cdot \dots \cdot P(X_2|X_1)?$$
For simplicity, take $n=3$:
$$P(X_2,X_3|X_1)=P(X_3|X_2,X_1) \cdot P(X_2|X_1)?$$
Now remember that each $P$ above is really a marginal over the $S_i$:
$$\sum_{S_1,S_2,S_3}P(X_2,X_3,S_1,S_2,S_3|X_1)=\sum_{S_1,S_2,S_3}P(X_3, S_1,S_2,S_3|X_2,X_1) \cdot \sum_{S_1',S_2',S_3'}P(X_2,S_1',S_2',S_3'|X_1)?$$
But that's not right. Applying the definition of $P(X_2,X_3|X_1)$ gives us only a single summation on the right side:
$$\sum_{S_1,S_2,S_3}P(X_2,X_3,S_1,S_2,S_3|X_1)=\sum_{S_1,S_2,S_3}P(X_3, S_1,S_2,S_3|X_2,X_1) \cdot P(X_2,S_1,S_2,S_3|X_1).$$
More to the point, we can apply similar reasoning to $P(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, eventually getting:
$$P(X_1,X_2,X_3)=\sum_{S_1,S_2,S_3}P(X_3|S_3)P(S_3|S_2)P(X_2|S_2)P(S_2|S_1)P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1).$$
***CAVEAT**: In the above equation and what follows, I assume that the $X_t$ are conditionally independent given $S_t$. This assumption makes the formulas more compact, but it isn't essential. To revoke the assumption, just replace $P(X_2|S_2)$ with $P(X_2|X_1,S_2)$ and so on.*

And that's the matrix product given in the article! To build up the product manually, work from right to left:
$$P(S_1)
=\left(\begin{array}{c}P(S_1=1)\\P(S_1=2)\end{array}\right)
=\boldsymbol{\pi}
=\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
$$P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1)=\boldsymbol{F}_1\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
$$\sum_{S_1}P(S_2|S_1)P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1)=\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_1\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
$$\sum_{S_1}P(X_2|S_2)P(S_2|S_1)P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1)=\boldsymbol{F}_2\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_1\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
$$\sum_{S_1,S_2}P(S_3|S_2)P(X_2|S_2)P(S_2|S_1)P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1)=\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_2\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_1\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
$$\sum_{S_1,S_2}P(X_3|S_3)P(S_3|S_2)P(X_2|S_2)P(S_2|S_1)P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1)=\boldsymbol{F}_3\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_2\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_1\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
$$\sum_{S_1,S_2,S_3}P(X_3|S_3)P(S_3|S_2)P(X_2|S_2)P(S_2|S_1)P(X_1|S_1)P(S_1)=\boldsymbol\iota'\boldsymbol{F}_3\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_2\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{F}_1\boldsymbol{P}'\boldsymbol{\pi}$$
I think it makes more sense to keep the product in that order, although you can take the transpose of the whole thing to get the article's expression. (Recall that $\boldsymbol{F}_t=\boldsymbol{F}_t'$.) Such minutiae aren't really too important. The big-picture takeaway is that this matrix product is not a product of scalar likelihoods for each $t$. It is sensitive to long-term correlations between the $S_t$, which supposedly can and should be ignored for the authors' purposes.

Comment: Chris thanks for your answer. If it's not too much trouble could you check if the following is correct?
$$P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)=E(E(P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1,S_{n-1},S_n)|S_{n-1},X_{n-1},\dots,X_1))=(P(S_{n-1}=1|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1)P(S_{n-1}=2|X_{n-1},\dots,X_1))' \cdot\boldsymbol{PF}_n\cdot\mathbf{1}$$

and 

$$P(X_2,\dots,X_n|X_0)=\boldsymbol{\pi}'\boldsymbol{PF}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{1}\dots\cdot(P(S_{n-2}=1|X_{n-2},\dots,X_0)P(S_{n-2}=2|X_{n-2},\dots,X_0))' \boldsymbol{PF}_{n-1}\cdot \mathbf{1}\cdot(P(S_{n-1}=1|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)P(S_{n-1}=2|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0))' \boldsymbol{PF}_n \cdot\mathbf{1}$$

Comment: Um, to be honest, I'm having trouble following what's going on in those equations. Perhaps you could edit the question to spell out the steps in painstaking detail? :)

Comment: For the first part:
$$\displaystyle P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)=E(E(P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_{n-1},S_n)|S_{n-1},X_{n-1},\dots,X_0))=E(F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_n=1)P(S_n=1|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)+F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_n=2)P(S_n=2|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0))=\sum^2_{i=1}[F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_n=1)P(S_n=1|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)+F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_n=2)P(S_n=2|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)]\cdot P(S_{n-1}|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0) $$

$$=(P(S_{n-1}=1|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)P(S_{n-1}=2|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0))' \cdot \boldsymbol{PF}_n \cdot \mathbf{1}$$

Comment: For the second part, I just apply this last formula to right hand side of 
$$P(X_1,\dots,X_n|X_0)=P(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0)\cdot P(X_{n-1}|X_{n-2},\dots,X_0)\cdot \dots \cdot P(X_1|X_0) $$

Comment: Apologies, I'm still not sure what each of the $E$ operators represents. Also, the index $i$ in the summation doesn't seem to be used. I hope you don't think I'm nitpicking; these details make it hard to see how the pieces fit together.

Comment: You're completely right Chris. I'm the one that should be apologizing for my errors.  As soon as I get home I'll revise it. the E is expectation (maybe I'm using it the wrong way...)

Comment: as for the 2nd part:
$$\displaystyle =\sum^2_{i=1}[F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_{n}=1)\cdot P(S_{n}=1|X_{n-1}\dots,X_0,S_{n-1}=i)+F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_{n}=2)\cdot P(S_{n}=2|X_{n-1}\dots,X_0,S_{n-1}=i)]\cdot P(S_{n-1}=i|X_{n-1}\dots,X_0)$$ 

which is equal to 

$$\displaystyle =\sum^2_{i=1}[F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_{n}=1)\cdot p_{i1}+F(X_n|X_{n-1},\dots,X_0,S_{n}=2)\cdot p_{i2}]\cdot P(S_{n-1}=i|X_{n-1}\dots,X_0)$$

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks, that part is clear. I can now see what I think is the root problem for the whole strategy: we do not have the hoped-for decomposition $P(X_3,X_2|X_1)=P(X_3|X_2,X_1)P(X_2|X_1)$. Each $P(\cdot)$ in the equation represents marginalizing $S_1,S_2,S_3$ out of the full joint distribution $P(X_1,X_2,X_3,S_1,S_2,S_3)$. The left side marginalizes once, but the right side marginalizes twice, so they're not equal after all! This problem is fundamentally why we need a product of matrices rather than a product of scalars. I can add more detail in the answer if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Chris, I would be really thankful if you could give me more details.